# When using jQueryUI .sortable() & CSS Multi-Column layout, part of an item moves to next column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I am using jQuery UI `.sortable()` on an unordered list to split a list into multiple columns. I would like the first column to be filled first based on the height of it's container before populating the next column, which seems to be working. However, with `#testing` set to certain heights, part of the item overlaps into the next column rather than the entire item.

In the example below, only part of the last item flows into the 2nd column instead of the entire `li` going to the next item.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-count: 2;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#sortable li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
  padding-left: 0em;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#testing {
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing">
  <ul id="sortable">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can change the height of `#testing` at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lavscokb/2/).

As a side note, eventually each list element will contain it's own div layout that fills the entire element. Is there a better/different way that I should be doing this?